# Post Viewmodel which contains multiple list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a viewmodel consisting 2 lists:

```
public class RandomViewmodel
{
        public List<Model1> Model1 { get; set; }
        public List<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I access these viewmodel to create view that works fine

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Model1.Count(); i++)
{
    x = i;
    var item = Model.Model1.ElementAt(i);
  <tr>                 
    <td>
        @Html.Editor("[" + i + "].Amount", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = item.Amount } })                       
    </td>
 </tr>
}

@for (int k=0; k < Model.Model2.Count; k++)
{
 x = x + 1;
 var bacc = Model.Model2.ElementAt(k);
 @Html.Hidden("[" + k + "].ID", bacc.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "[" + k + "].ID" } })

 <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
     <td style="padding-left: 25px;">
          @(x+1) @bacc.name
     </td>
     <td class="adder_table_right" width="130px">
         @Html.Editor("[" + k + "].MiscAmount1", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     </td>
     <td class="adder_table_right" width="130px">
         @Html.Editor("[" + k + "].MiscAmount2", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     </td>
 </tr>                    
}
```

---

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Index(RandomViewModel vm)
```

Now when I hit submit button, I can see that the viewmodel object `vm` receives NULL for both of the models.

Comment: Your generating `name` attributes which have no relationship at all to your model - its `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Model1.Count; i++) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model1[i]Amount) }` and similar for the 2nd loop.

Comment: And refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand how to bind to collections

Comment: The name attribute belongs to the second model of my viewmodel 

public List<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }

moreover, this data is coming fine in my view. But when submitting value the post action receives null for the viewmodel

Comment: I guess you did not bother to read the link! Or try the correct code in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked out. Really appreciate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should reference to each list in your Model.

and `value` Attributes will be auto-initialize when you are using Html Helpers

use this codes it should work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Model1.Count(); i++)
{
x = i;
var item = Model.Model1.ElementAt(i);
<tr>                 
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model1[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control"})                       
    </td>
</tr>
}


@for (int k=0; k < Model.Model2.Count; k++)
{
 x = x + 1;
 var bacc = Model.Model2.ElementAt(k);
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Model2[i].ID)
 <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
     <td style="padding-left: 25px;">
          @(x+1) @bacc.name
     </td>
     <td class="adder_table_right" width="130px">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model2[i].MiscAmount1, new { @class = "form-control" })
     </td>
     <td class="adder_table_right" width="130px">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model2[i].MiscAmount2, new { @class = "form-control" })

     </td>
 </tr>                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use @Html.EditorFor to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the naming convention, which got resolved after I go through the following article referred by  Stephen Muecke of stackoverflow.

This is for other fellow developer, if they got stuck in the same situation like mine. Please go through this post first, it really helped a lot.

[Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Happy coding ;)